# Why are compiler outputs so different for this simple function?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, c++14, clang++

I ask the C++ compiler to generate a machine-coded function that sums the elements of a const `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>

int sum(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    int s = 0;
    for(const auto e:v) s += e;
    return s;
}
```

I ask compiler x86_64 GCC 7.2 with a `-O2`. It says just:

```
sum(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&):
  mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi]
  mov rcx, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
  xor eax, eax
  cmp rdx, rcx
  je .L4
.L3:
  add eax, DWORD PTR [rdx]
  add rdx, 4
  cmp rdx, rcx
  jne .L3
  rep ret
.L4:
  rep ret
```

I ask the same to compiler Clang 4.0.0 with `-O1`, `-O2` and `-O3`.  Well! That's a full essay. It just manipulates some adjectives in his essay across `-O1`, `-O2` and `-O3`.

Similar cases are with x86_64 ICC 17 with `-O2` and with x86_64 CL 19.

And I go back to compiler x86_64 GCC 7.2 with a `-O3`. x86_64 GCC 7.2 now gives a lengthy output.

Comment: It would probably be better to post a full-working example with code that either can be compiled or a link to goldbolt with the code. Right now, answers will probably not help you. Also, although the question is funny to read, using terms as specific as possible instead of "essay" etc will help people to understand your question.

Comment: It's hard to explain assembly without seeing it, but my guess is you could be seeing "loop unrolling", a technique to make code run faster by using more instructions.

Comment: Without the full test code, we just can guess. So my guess is that the other compilers (and GCC -O3) have implemented "loop unrolling" optimisation, thus resulting in a long assembly code, but with less jumps than the GCC -O2 one.

Comment: Well, what else would you expect? Optimization may involve complicated code. If you pass -Os (optimize for size), clang gives 10 lines of assembly.

Comment: This function is trivially vectorizable, so it's no wonder compilers vectorize it.

Comment: @Jens I have used https://godbolt.org.

Comment: @user62039 godbolt has a "Share" button where you can create a link so others can see the code, assembly, and everything else you're looking at.

Comment: @user62039 You can share the real example and other people can take a look at it. Instead of guessing what you did, we could now take a look. On goldbolt, select the "Share" menu and create a link to your example, e.g. https://godbolt.org/g/yN8AR6

Comment: @Fanael: I understand that this is trivially vectorisable. But, do you mean that those vectorised commands actually take less machine cycles? I was of the thought that vectorised commands will actually not be so many in numbers to just do a sum.

Comment: @Jens: Suppose my purpose is to create a `dll` that consists of a function `..sum(...)` that adds elements of an `std::vector<int>`. I would think this makes complete sense.

Comment: @user62039 If you pass different optimization options compilers will generate different code. Different compilers have different strattegies for optimization, e.g. one uses loop-unrolling by default, others don't. If you compile with -O3 or -funroll-loops with gcc the code will look more like the clang variant. I am not sure that will answer your question because I still don't understand it.

Comment: You know that there is `std::accumulate` in the standard library? It does exactly what your function does.

Comment: @user62039 What do you expect? That every compiler generates identical code?

Comment: @tambre: He he! These words 'It says' just came out of my mind being blown by the differences given by different compilers.

Comment: Length of assembly is a questionable metric to start with, but when loops are involved it's just completely useless. Yes, the vectorized and unrolled version is longer, but it needs far fewer iterations on the same input.

Comment: I suggest posting a dynamic trace of the assembly being executed, and we compare that.

Answer (score 2):

What I think your question asks is:

> why is so much code produced for such a simple thing?

To which the answer is long but goes something like this:

Modern memory architectures achieve more throughput when we manipulate memory...

- in blocks
- in parallel
- on memory address boundaries that are efficient for the given hardware.

So the compiler is attempting to optimise the case of a long vector by vectorising/parallelising the operations as much as possible, taking into account the characteristics of the memory architecture.

But not all vectors are multiples of the number of items that can be treated efficiently as a block.

So the beginning and end of the vector is treated separately, with specific operations, while the bulk of a (long) vector is treated by the clever vectorised code in the middle.

Comment: Thanks! After reading your answer, especially that you said about the "beginning and end... treated separately" and looking back into the GCC -O3 output more carefully, I notice that large chunk of the emitted code is actually running only once for the border elements.